# Why apache is unable to write with permission set as 2775?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, sudo, php

I have installed `LAMP` as:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

If I understand correctly, `apache` server will be running with `sudo` privileges? If yes, for a `php` script to be able to write in its own directory does it only require `RWX` for root user?

It doesn't work for me. I have to give `777` privileges to the directory and the script for it write a new file into the particular directory. I do not understand, how is it functioning. Why cannot the apache, that is running as root able to write when `2775` have been set up earlier?

I had earlier given permissions as : `(using shell commands)`

```
groupadd www;
usermod -a -G www $(whoami);
adduser $(whoami) sudo;
default_conf_file_path="/etc/apache2/sites-available/";
default_conf_file=$default_conf_file_path"000-default.conf";
DocumentRoot=$(grep "DocumentRoot"  $default_conf_file);
DocumentRoot=${DocumentRoot#*/};
DocumentRoot=/$DocumentRoot;
chown -R root:www $DocumentRoot;
chmod 2775 $DocumentRoot;
find $DocumentRoot -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;
find $DocumentRoot -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

Comment: Note that Apache workers never run as 'root' or super user unless explicitly configured to (and that's a dangerous configuration).  The master process may run as root but all workers which actually access web files and write to disk on behalf of web applications run as `www-data` in a default installation.

Comment: @ThomasW. I have added the shell commands I run after installing `lamp`

Comment: @ThomasW. How to give worker threads the write permission?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add "www-data" user into your newly created group "www" using (gpasswd -a www-data www)